# PL/SQL Select column value into a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a View that I've created and I need to extract some tokens from it.I read about BULK COLLECT but I don't think that it will work for me as later on I'll need the extracted values stored separately.

`SELECT TOKEN FROM MAPPING_VIEW WHERE USERNAME='Peter'`.

Here for example I'l get returned a number of tokens (the number of tokens returned can not be predicted).
I'm pretty new at pl/sql can someone give me directions on how to store the extracted tokens in different variables? As I mentioned I don't know how many tokens may be returned beforehand.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete code of your stored procedure (or function). [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  as I've said I have no idea how to even begin as I don't know a method to create a number of variables that would correspond to the column's values

Comment: if you are new at pl/sql you can take a look at : http://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor/

Comment: Presumably your table holds token name and value columns? If so, you'll have to bulk collect into a table of records.

Comment: *"as later on I'll need the extracted values stored separately."* - You mean you want them to be stored into another table?

Comment: I don' want to store them into another table. I just need a way to extract all values from that column and display them in a way that I can differentiate them from one another. Just thought that by storing them into variables it would be easier since one column value typically a string of about 100 characters.

Comment: If you want to put them in different variables then you will need to define all of those variables at the start. I’m not sure that will work if you don’t know how many you are going to need. An alternative would be to load them into an associative array indexed by some unique key (not sure what that will be in your example). Then you could refer to `mytokens('Peter')`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
DECLARE
 TYPE rec_token IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
      l_rec_token rec_token;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT token
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_rec_token
      FROM mapping_view
      WHERE username='Peter';
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      l_rec_token := rec_token();
  END ;

  IF l_rec_token.COUNT >0 THEN
  FOR i IN l_rec_token.FIRST..l_rec_token.LAST
  LOOP
    <doSomeThing>
  END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```